# nonlinear combinatoric optimization problem

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, discrete-optimization

I need to solve a problem to choose $K$ elements from a set of size $N$. The objective function to minimize is highly nonlinear and rather complicated, so picking one element might change the "value" of all other elements significantly.

My general question is: Is there anything I can do aside from brute forcing through all combinations? I'd normally use heuristic methods for this, but I need a verified optimal solution this time.

I've tried to identify some elements that are not part of the solution beforehand, or find some upper/lower bound on the value of each element, but no luck so far.

If anyone wants to try I'll write the objective function down, but I don't think there's an easy solution to this.

I am given an $n\times n$ matrix $A$ is symmetric and has only positive elements on the main diagonal.  In fact $A = (S^T S)^{-1}$.

> Choose $k$ integers $\vec{t}=[t_1,...,t_k]\in\mathbb{N}$, 
>   $1\leq t_i\leq n$ such that: $$\min\limits_\vec{t}(||diag(A)||_2)\qquad A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$$
>
> Where every $t_i$ added (iteratively) changes every element of the matrix $A$ by $$a_{x,y,t_{i}}=a_{x,y}-\frac{a_{x,t}a_{t,y}}{1+a_{t,t}}$$

Comment: If the objective function is arbitrary, then of course brute force is the only way to find the optimal $k$-subset.  However it seems your "evaluation function" only depends on the diagonal entries of $A$.  Is there a matrix that exists before any $t_i$ are chosen?

Comment: yes, there is (It's the inverse of the squared system matrix for a fluid network $(S^TS)^{-1}$). The evaluation function only depends on the diagonal elements, but every $t_i$ added will change those entries depending on other (non-diagonal) elements. My real problem is that those entries change too so i can't really estimate what happens when adding more than 2

Comment: I'm checking my suspicion that the *order* in which $t_i$'s are chosen makes a difference, so that a *sequence* is being chosen rather than a *subset*.  Just to clarify, we are forbidden to choose (for example) the same $t_i$ more than once?

Comment: Yes i can't choose the same $t_i$ more than once. But the order should not matter. If it does then i have done a mistake before. I got this formula because i want to append rows with only one $1$ and rest $0$ to $S$ and found my equation by using the sherman-morrison-formula.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain that connection with the matrix $S$, e.g. the dimensions of $S$ as related to $k$.  Context is more useful than you might expect as a new user.

Comment: Well okay, but i don't think i have much helpfull information. S is sparse, quadratic and quite big (in the end it will be about 2000x2000, but i only need to verify my solution for some example systems about 20x20)

Comment: Knowing that $S$ is square is helpful.  How is $k$, number of rows to add, selected?

Comment: User supplied, i calculate the optimal distribution of sensors in a network, so it could be anything between 1 and $n-1$ depending on the cost of adding sensors. It should generally be much smaller than $n$ (otherwise the sherman-morrison-formula would not make sense).